# How can I create xy line chart in java with values from a database?

Tags: java

How can I create xy line chart in java with values from a database?
I see this tutorial on internet, but dont know how to replace the default values ​​with values ​​from the database.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo6.htm

I tried to override these values ​​by the result of the following query, but it was not possible ... Does someone can help me please? I've turned the internet and found nothing that could help me in concrete. I am new to java programming and liked to learn, however I'm stuck on this problem.

My query where I pretend read values:

```
SELECT p1.`date`
,p2.`date`
     , p1.`temperature` as `temperature of Termomether1`
     , p2.`temperature` as `temperature of Termomether2`
FROM   (SELECT idTermomether, date, temperature
        FROM records
        WHERE idTermomether LIKE 'Termomether1' and date like '2014-06-01') p1
       LEFT  JOIN (SELECT idTermomether, date,  temperature
                   FROM records
                   WHERE idTermomether1 LIKE 'Termomether2' and date like '2014-06-01') p2
       ON p1.date = p2.date;
```

or the same query write for another way

```
SELECT r.date, r1.temperature, r2.temperature
FROM records r, records r1, records r2
WHERE r.date = r1.date AND r.date = r2.date AND
      r1.idTermomether = 'Termomether1' AND r2.idTermomether = 'Termomether2' AND r1.date like '2014-06-01' and r2.date like '2014-06-01';
```

Thank you all for your attention and for any help you can give me.

Comment: And what does the above query have to do with Java? And what does your question have to do with charting or plotting when you obviously do not know: How to get results of a SELECT statement in Java? This is your question in fact...

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the help. I already made ​​the connection to the database. And also got an out to do the graphics I saw this video: youtube.com/watch?v=z0fLprufs0o However only appears me a line and if you do a search within one week, just asks me one result per day, and not the right number should appear. Needed so that someone could help me do things correctly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to break up your problem into smaller and smaller sub problems until you know how to code each and every sub problem.

Here's one way to break your problem down into sub problems.

1. You have to connect to the database.
2. You have to execute a query against the database.
3. You have to store the results of the query in a List.
4. You have to disconnect from the database.
5. You have to set up the X Y chart.
6. You have to set the points on the chart with the query results in the List.

This is how you code any problem.  You break it down into as many sub problems as necessary until you know how to code each and every sub problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the help. I already made ​​the connection to the database. And also got an out to do the graphics I saw this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0fLprufs0o  However only appears me a line and if you do a search within one week, just asks me one result per day, and not the right number should appear. Needed so that someone could help me do things correctly. Is it possible?

Comment: @Mary.J: Sure, it's possible.  But not on Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is for answering specific questions.  What you need is a Java tutor.  Hire one.